# Angular 2 dependency Zone.js

Tags: angular

I am working on a big project that consists of a bunch of modules. I implemented my module using **Angular 2 rc.3**. I am also using webpack to bundle the module. The output of webpack is 3 files: app.js, polyfills.js and vendor.js.
app.js contains application code, vendors.js contains imported angular 2's modules and rxjs operators and polyfills.js contains reflect-metadata and **zone.js** libraries.
polyfills.js is compiled from polyfill.ts that contains:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
require('zone.js/dist/zone');
```

My module is then used as a part of a big single page application.
My huge concern is the **zone.js dependency**. It patches functions in the global scope. Including this library in my module affects other teams' modules. And this is not acceptable.
There was an issue with the zone.js while transforming a jquery jqXHR to a ES2016 Promise. A jqXHR object is thenable that resolves to itself when rejected. Because of this the resolvePromise function of the zone.js goes into a infinite loop trying to resolve that thenable. And that leads to the browser hanging. I resolved that issue but the main problem is that this issue was not even in my module, but in module of other team.

So you see how adding zone.js to my module can lead to errors in other modules. And I can not allow that.

**My question is how can I sandbox zone.js only for my module** so it could not affect other modules? It is a peaty if Angular team didn't think of it because I belive it will be a blocker not only for me but for other developers and companies too.

Comment: The relevant bug report was submitted for Angular team https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9995